# How to change user input in DataGridView cell from dot into a comma?

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-input

I would really appreciate your help.

I have a DataGridView where user will be giving us double (2,43 etc).

I want to write a function which can detect if user puts dot in place of comma and just change it itself or treat it as comma for the calculations.

If it was a console app I would just simply write something like

```
public void ChangeToComma()
{
    var someUserInput;
    char arr[] = someUserInput.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0, i < someUserInput.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char[i] == ".")
        {
            char[i] = ",";
        }
    }
}
```

That would be the logic I would use (maybe not correct but I just wanted to show better what I want to do).

I'm just starting with other than console apps so I'm stuck here :/

What I don't even have a slightest idea about (how to do it) is:

1. How to go through every single char in a specified DataGridView cell?
2. How to avoid changing every single dot in every cell of this DataGridView? Some of them are with text so they might contain dots.

Comment: Look into the [CellValidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating?view=netframework-4.8) event which occurs when a cell loses input focus, enabling content validation.

Comment: would you not just change the language type settings to say UK so that 3.141 comes out as that not 3,141

Comment: @BugFinder I have a Polish settings so in fact if it works like that it should already be this way itself but it doesn't :( In Poland we use commas as default.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thank you I'm going to check it right now

Comment: @San you're welcome. On another note, if you use that event, you can combine that with a quick regex match to validate the input by the user.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I'm afraid I don't know what it is about and how but I will look for some informations about it and try to figure it out :) Good to know something new :)

Comment: @San if you get stuck and something isn't working, please come back and we would be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by replacing the comma for a dot using the replace method contained in system

```
double value = double.Parse(dataGridViewTest.Rows[4].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
dataGridViewTest
.Rows[4]
.Cells[2].Value = value.ToString("N2");
```

"N2" as a parameter for method to string will set the value as decimal with two digits at the end.

You can also validate the input before saving the data to avoid users insert wrong the information in a wrong format.